# Creating a database failed when adding a link to odoo 11 addons_path in docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, odoo-11

I am running odoo 11 with docker, when adding the addons path, I create the database successfully, if I add any path to my module, this error will occur.

```html
KeyError: ('ir.model.data', <function IrModelData.xmlid_lookup at 0x7fba098f1d90>, 'web.assets_frontend')
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: web.assets_frontend
```